# SSH key setup to login multiple hosts without password

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

I installed Putty on my local Windows machine A. I am connecting to remote linux server B from A. From B, I want to connect to multiple other remote machines C, D, E, F etc without entering password all the time.

Is there any way to achieve this ? I tried setting up SSH keys from A to B. But to login to multiple other hosts from B, do I need to set keys on every other hosts ?

Comment: I think [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311447/how-do-i-ssh-to-machine-a-via-b-in-one-command) answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to set up `ssh-key` authentication from Host B to all hosts. to connect from B to other hosts with out password. You can copy public key generated in B host to all other hosts in `authorized_keys file`

There is another method also using `sshpass` .

But it wont be secure format of using `sshpass` is as below:

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh username@hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add a private key(*) in your SSH config on host B, and the matching public key in the `authorized_keys` file on C,D,E,F.

(*) Which is best kept distinct from the one you use to login from A to B.